# prismaObjectType usage produces a union type that is too complex to represent

Tags: typescript, prisma, nexus-prisma

I have a node project written in typescript with graphQl and prisma-nexus.

the usage of prismaObjectType from `import { prismaObjectType } from 'nexus-prisma'` produces a union type that is too complex to represent.

I can still use the project in dev but when I build it using `tsc -p` the build fails with this error `error TS2590: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.`

does anyone come across this issue ? any idea how to solve it or at least to ignore it when building the project ?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Timestamps from this and GH post are close so you may have found this, but info here: https://github.com/prisma/nexus-prisma/issues/291 (recommendation is dropping to TS 3.4.x

Comment: thank you for this input this will work, but i want to work with the latest version of typescript

Answer (score 1):

This [solution](https://github.com/graphql-nexus/nexus-schema-plugin-prisma/issues/284#issuecomment-535561384) was posted on an issue for `nexus-schema-plugin-prisma` on GitHub.

Where ever you use `prismaExtendType`, also pass a string of the object type as a type argument. 
For example, if you have a prisma "User" model type, change:

```
prismaObjectType({/*config object*/})
```

to:

```
prismaObjectType<"User">({/*config object*/})
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment a bit:

There is currently a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/prisma/nexus-prisma/issues/291) filed for this. The recommended solution is to drop Typescript to `3.4.X`.

Prisma 1 is currently being phased out in favor of [v2 / Photon](https://www.prisma.io/blog/announcing-prisma-2-zq1s745db8i5). Although continued maintenance is planned, it looks like most resources are being shifted away:

> Prisma 1 will continue to be maintained. However, most Prisma engineering resources will go into the development of [Prisma 2](https://github.com/prisma/prisma2)
>
> There will be no new features developed for Prisma 1.

I do hope this issue is fixed, but I think the recommended solution is upgrading to Photon and moving away from Prisma 1.

Comment: there are tons of issues still to be fixed in order to stabilize Prisma2, at first i wanted to develop with prisma2 but as nothing is clear to me when there will be a stable version of Prisma that can be used in production